# Need to add multiple inlcude devpkey.h in my cmake project in msvc

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, cmake

Included that header files of my BundleController class are included multiple times devpkey.h header file. So MSVC give errors like below;

```
**Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2374   'DEVPKEY_Device_Address': redefinition; multiple initialization (compiling source file BundleController.cpp) C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\shared\devpkey.h   66  
Error   C2374   'DEVPKEY_Device_Address': redefinition; multiple initialization (compiling source file main.cpp)    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\shared\devpkey.h    66  
Error   C2374   'DEVPKEY_Device_AssignedToGuest': redefinition; multiple initialization (compiling source file BundleController.cpp)    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\shared\devpkey.h    167 
Error   C2374   'DEVPKEY_Device_AssignedToGuest': redefinition; multiple initialization (compiling source file main.cpp)    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\shared\devpkey.h    167 
Error   C2374   'DEVPKEY_Device_BaseContainerId': redefinition; multiple initialization (compiling source file Bundlecontroller.cpp)    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\shared\devpkey.h    74  
Error   C2374   'DEVPKEY_Device_BaseContainerId': redefinition; multiple initialization (compiling source file main.cpp)    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\shared\devpkey.h    74  
Error   C2374   'DEVPKEY_Device_BiosDeviceName': redefinition; multiple initialization (compiling source file BundleController.cpp)     C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\shared\devpkey.h    153 
Error   C2374   'DEVPKEY_Device_BiosDeviceName': redefinition; multiple initialization (compiling source file main.cpp) C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\shared\devpkey.h    153 
.
.
.**
```

I need to include multiple times devpkey.h header file to my project, how can I add that file?

Project compilation tool is cmake.

Comment: `INITGUID` must be defined only before one include. in your case you *#inclide <initguid.h>* before *#include <devpkey.h>* in many files. you need only *#include <devpkey.h>* and in single file include *#inclide <initguid.h>* before *#include <devpkey.h>*. also may be need use [*/showIncludes*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/showincludes-list-include-files?view=msvc-170) compiler option for view exactly includes order

Comment: @RbMm It works. If you can write as an answer, it could help other people that getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in such situation always need look code and try understand source of error. `DEVPKEY_Device_Address` (and another symbols in question) defined with [`DEFINE_DEVPROPKEY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/define-devpropkey) macro. based on - are [`INITGUID`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/including-guids-in-driver-code) is defined - `DEFINE_DEVPROPKEY` expanded to declaration or definition. if not defined `INITGUID`, before include *devpkey.h* ( usually this is done not direct but by `#include <initguid.h>`, because here exist additional important macros ), we will be have only declarations of `DEVPKEY_Device_Address` and other symbols, without actual definitions. as result we got error - unresolved symbol on link time. if include *initguid.h* before every include *devpkey.h* - we will be have multiple definitions of symbols. usual this must not lead to error, because was `DECLSPEC_SELECTANY` in symbol definition, which can expand to [`__declspec( selectany )`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/selectany?view=msvc-170)

> *Tells the compiler that the declared global data item (variable or object) is a pick-any COMDAT (a packaged function).At link time, if
> multiple definitions of a COMDAT are seen, the linker picks one and
> discards the rest.*

but look like your comiler dont support/understand __declspec( selectany ), if you got error *C2374*

in this case - need have declaration in any file, which use symbol and definition only in any one. for this in some selected source file do

```
#include <initguid.h>
// ...
#include <devpkey.h>
```

and in another files - only

```
#include <devpkey.h>
```

without `#include <initguid.h>` before